# Reference Request for Fourier Analysis Dedicated to Signal Processing

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis

Some background about myself, I am an electrical and computer engineering in my junior year. I am interested in mathematical analysis in various fields $($real, complex, functional$)$ and have self studied them. I am currently being introduced to Fourier analysis in continuous-time and discrete-time domain in my signal processing course.

> Therefore, I was wondering if someone can recommend me some excellent books/notes that maintain a rigorous introduction on Fourier Analysis with theorems and proofs and its applications dedicated to only signals and systems.

The purpose for this request is that I have seen many books (even famous ones like Stein's book) but they kind of diverge their focus and interest on PDEs mainly and other physical systems.

**Edit** : I have accepted Manlio's answer since it satisfies the requirements for my question. However, Any other recommendations are still welcomed and I would be also grateful. I also hope this question is beneficial to anyone who shares my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possibility:

*Gasquet, Claude; Witomski, Patrick*, Fourier analysis and applications. Filtration, numerical calculus, wavelets, Enseignement des Mathématiques. Paris: Masson. xi, 355 p. (1995). [ZBL0914.94001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0914.94001).

It explores several aspects of the theory, but has a lot of focus on applications and algorithms.

Comment: I have taken interest in the book you have recommended in fact it provides an excellent mathematical approach with great modelling and applications. Thank you